# .Net - Disabling going back one page when user clicks "Backspace" keyboard button

Tags: javascript, browser, navigation

Basically sometimes I need to show a form that is pre-populated with a record. Depending on the users privileges, he may or may not be able to edit the data.

The problem I'm encountering is that sometimes a user will try to edit a textbox that's been disabled by clicking on it and hitting the "backspace" button to edit the text. This causes the browser to go back one page... Annoying.

Comment: How do you wish to distinguish this behaviour from a user who prefers to use keyboard navigation and genuinely wishes to go back? Now you're going to annoy them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's asp .net you can simply do it like this:

```
<script language=javascript>   

    function cancelBack()   
    {   
        if ((event.keyCode == 8 ||    
           (event.keyCode == 37 && event.altKey) ||    
           (event.keyCode == 39 && event.altKey))   
            &&    
           (event.srcElement.form == null || event.srcElement.isTextEdit == false)   
          )   
        {   
            event.cancelBubble = true;   
            event.returnValue = false;   
        }   
    }   

</script>   
<body onkeydown=cancelBack()>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the keyboard event in javascript and stop it from executing. What server-side code you are using (ASP.NET) doesn't make a difference.

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
 if(event.keyCode == 8)
    return false;
}
```

*Just tested in Chrome and it seems to work*

Comment: You have a major typo, the code should be

          window.onkeydown = function (event) {
              if (event.keyCode == 8) {
                  return false;
              }
          }

Answer (score 0):

Place this under  in the document ready function if you have one

```
window.onkeydown = function (event) 
{
          if (event.keyCode == 8) {
              return false;
          }
}
```